# How to cause a REGEX pattern to match only specific words without using capturing group?

Tags: regex, boost, notepad++

I have some difficulties extracting the function name and the arguments using regex (perl)
In the following declaration

```
(defun foo#bar (arg1 arg2/param1 param2) 
       ;function definition goes here
)
```

> the regex pattern I'm looking for should match *ONLY*
>
> > foo#bar arg1 arg2

I know of `\K` to reset matched text at this point. For instance, matching "foo\Kbar" will not match bar". **It will match "foobar", but will pretend that only "bar" matches.**

So in my case using \K would give

`(defun \K.*\(.*\/` --> `foo#bar (arg1 arg2/` while I need `foo#bar arg1 arg2`

I don't know how to isolate the following arguments (0 to n occurences) enclosed between the "(" and the "/" without using capturing groups.

Thanks ahead for the replies

*More Info on the "why"*

I'm trying to parse a user defined language in Notepad++ using the functionList.xml file

```
<parser id="my_language_name" displayName="My language" commentExpr=";">
                <function
                    mainExpr="\(defun.*\(.*/.*\)"
                    displayMode="$functionName">
                    <functionName>
                        <nameExpr expr="(?<=\(defun).*(?= \()."/>
                    </functionName>
                </function>
</parser>
```

I've tried to use capturing groups in the nameExpr node with no luck till now.

Comment: so you just want to check if args are present but not capture them?

Comment: No I need them, I the function name and the arguments like so: foo#bar arg1 arg2

Comment: Why can't you use capturing groups? Is that a limitation of Notepad++? If so, how do you return anything with a regex besides whether there was a match or not?

Comment: In the FunctionList.xml file we can define a function parser for user defined languages, I've been trying to use capturing groups in the regex node but nothing worked... <nameExpr expr="[regex pattern here]"/>

Comment: @danie7LT You should include that info in your question. The examples in the [Notepad++ documentation for custom function parsers](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/function-list.html) show capturing groups, so I don't think that's your problem.

Comment: from NOTEPAD++ site "Notepad++ regular expressions use the standard PCRE (Perl) syntax" that's why I inserted it [http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions#Groups]

Comment: @danie7LT Despite the name, PCRE is not the same as Perl regex. Based on that link, Notepad++ actually uses Boost's regex implementation, which is neither PCRE nor Perl.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot I switched perl to boost, thank you

Comment: Boost does not support an infinite width lookbehind that could be used to match something after a known keyword. However, I think you should look for other ways since there are specific means for that in grammar files for editors.

Comment: So, your language has only functions to parse, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yes only functions, could you explain a bit more what you meant in your previous comment ("specific means for that in grammar files for editors")? Thank you

Comment: [Notepad++ does not support what you want to do](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27046002/notepad-custom-function-list-basic). [You can't add a new language here in a dynamically way.](https://sourceforge.net/p/npp-plugins/discussion/670934/thread/080ccc41/#b99c) Instead, try to build a UDL (user-defined language).